# Do I need NuGet package explorer with .NET CORE?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package-explorer

I am very very new to both NuGet and .NET core. I was wondering how to create Nuget pakages while upgrading my code-base from classic .NET to CORE and I think I came across two tutorials

1. Using .NET CORE CLI `dotnet` command
2. I was going through a Pluralsight tutorial and they mentioned `NuGet Package Explorer`

Now, My questions is that with advent of `dotnet command` in CORE CLI, how relevant is NuGet Package Explorer if my needs are very limited to creating and publishing packages?

Comment: @MartinLiversage: You can turn it into an answer if you want and I will be able to accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NuGet Package Explorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer) is a GUI tool for opening and displaying the contents of NuGet packages. It can also be used to create NuGet packages. However, using the [NuGet command line tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference) is much simpler. Using NuGet Package Explorer is entirely optional. It's just a tool that some people find useful.

.NET Core is orthogonal to NuGet Package Explorer and the advent of .NET Core does not change the usefulness of NuGet Package Manager.